# Python, ElementTree как добавить потомков?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Парсю xml (в нем нет item`s), передаю в функцию child. Как в той функции добавить в child items чтобы при сохранении в вызывающей функции они были сохранены. Конечный вид xml файла:

```xml
<data>
    <test name="Prot_field work="1">
        <hash>
            <item>c6a478ac01a32abf6075cfffb1c3cbaee404c7369543f7bf4624a3c751ab1221</item>
            <item>1115e709e3ea8c63129fdde39d93d7eed66d57e857249da18125f915a132e10a</item>
        </hash>
    </test>
</data>
```

```py
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    sameFunction(child)
tree.write('file.xml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью функции `SubElement` можно добавить один элемент в другой, например вот так:

```py
def add_item(child, value):
    item = ET.SubElement(child, 'item')
    item.text = value
```

Тогда ваш код примет такой вид:

```py
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    add_item(child, '12345')  # вдруг вам нужно не просто пустой тег добавить, а со значением

tree.write('file.xml')
```

Comment: Тэг добавляется непосредственно в child, а как добавить потомка в уже имеющийся тэг внутри child ?

Comment: не помогло   hash = ET.SubElement(child, 'hash')    item = ET.SubElement(hash,'item1')
    item.text = value

Comment: Добавился новый тэг hash, а не использовался уже имеющийся.

Answer (score 0):

используя предложенный выше вариант функция вышла такой:

```
def add_item(child, value):
    item = ET.SubElement(child[0], 'item') # тэги считаются с 0
    item.text = value
```